# Googletest compilation errors: ‘xyzTest’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, googletest

I am learning TDD, using GoogleTest framework. I have successfully built Gtest and have been able to build and run the samples. However, when I tried a simple sample I wrote, I am getting compilation errors.

Here is the source and the build commands I used:

```
// ################################################
//proj1.h
#ifndef  __SCRATCH_PROJ1_H
#define  __SCRATCH_PROJ1_H

int addOne(int i);

#endif /*__SCRATCH_PROJ1_H */

// ################################################

//proj1.cpp
#include "proj1.h"

int addOne(int i){
    return i+1;
}


// ################################################
//proj1_unittest.cpp

#include "proj1.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

// Test Function
TEST(addOneTest, Positive) {
    EXPECT_EQ(1,addOneTest(0));            // <- Line # 24
    EXPECT_EQ(2,addOneTest(1));            // <- Line # 25
    EXPECT_EQ(40320, addOneTest(40319));   // <- Line # 26
}

TEST(addOneTest, Negative) {
    EXPECT_FALSE(addOneTest(-1));          // <- Line # 30
}


GTEST_API_ int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Console output:

> g++ -isystem ${GTEST_DIR}/include -pthread -c
>   /home/user1/scratch/proj1_unittest.cpp 
>   /home/user1/scratch/proj1_unittest.cpp: In member function ‘virtual
>   void addOneTest_Positive_Test::TestBody()’:
>   /home/user1/scratch/proj1_unittest.cpp:24:5: error: ‘addOneTest’ was
>   not declared in this scope
>   /home/user1/scratch/proj1_unittest.cpp:25:5: error: ‘addOneTest’ was
>   not declared in this scope
>   /home/user1/scratch/proj1_unittest.cpp:26:5: error: ‘addOneTest’ was
>   not declared in this scope /home/user1/scratch/proj1_unittest.cpp: In
>   member function ‘virtual void addOneTest_Negative_Test::TestBody()’:
>   /home/user1/scratch/proj1_unittest.cpp:30:5: error: ‘addOneTest’ was
>   not declared in this scope

Judging from the line numbers in the error messages, it seems that the EXPECT_* macros have not been defined - BUT, I have included gtest/gtest.h in the compilation unit.

What is causing these errors - and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says, `addOneTest` was not declared anywhere. I'm guessing you meant to call `addOne` instead.

Comment: After a good night's sleep, as soon as I looked at the code, I spotted the embarrassing error. I wish I could delete my question, but since you answered it already, I will accept your answer.